# переключение между формами с помощью горячих клавиш

Tags: java

Здравствуйте. 
Привожу задание:

> *"Создать две формы: первую ­ с трема полями ­ “Фамилия”, “Имя” и “Отчество” и кнопой, и вторую с одним полем “Ф.И.О.” и кнопкой. При
>   нажатии на кнопку первая форма должна подменяться второй, и наоборот.
>   При этом поля формы должны заполняться автоматически: если в первой
>   форме были введены данные, они должны оказаться во второй форме, и
>   наоборот."*

Это сделал. А дальше:

> *"Усложнённое задание: сделать так, чтобы переключение между двумя формами в обе стороны работало также при нажатии на Ctrl+Enter."*

Вот этого у меня и не 
получается. Как делать - не знаю.

Comment: при нажатии на <Ctrl+Enter>.

Comment: fx? второй сценарий сделать, нет?

Comment: @GenCloud, у меня не получается сделать переключение между формами при нажатии пользователем клавиш Ctrl+Enter. Т. е. раньше, чтобы переключиться между ними, пользователь жал на кнопку (на каждой их них текстовое поле ввода и кнопка), а нужно, чтобы он теперь нажал Ctrl+Enter, и одно окно подменило другое.